# Typescript map function return new object not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm new to typescript

```
export class Reward {
    id: number;
    point: number;
    status: Status;


    constructor(id: number, point: number, status: Status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.point = point;
        this.status = Status.NONE;
    }

}

export enum Status {
    CLAIMED,
    AVAILABLE,
    NONE
}



   public getRewardsOf(numberOfDay: number): Array<Reward> {
       return this.availableRewards.map((reward: Reward, index: number) => {
            if (index == (numberOfDay - 1)) {
                return new Reward(reward.id, reward.point, Status.AVAILABLE);
            } else {
                return reward;
            }
        });
    }
```

the if doesn't work for me. It still returns the same old object (the status value is the same). it's supposed to be different even though I create a new object.

It works when I use

```
 if (index == (numberOfDay - 1)) {
         return {
                    'id': reward.id,
                    'point': reward.point,
                    'status': Status.AVAILABLE
                };
            } else {
                return reward;
            }
```

if so I lose the power of typescript

Comment: What makes you think it's the old object?  As it stands, this code does make a copy of `Reward` (but that assumes that `Reward` is not doing anything crazy in its constructor like `return point.reward`).

Comment: @jagthebeetle has hooked you up below. A further design option is to create an instance method `Reward.withStatus(newStatus: Status)` that returns the current object with the new status. You will still need to fix your constructor.

Comment: ok thanks it was my mistake hardcode the value in the constructor

Answer (score 5):

Your constructor is hardcoding the value `Status.NONE`:

```
...
this.status = Status.NONE
...
```

This will effectively discard the status argument passed to the constructor.

If you wish to provide Status.NONE as a default parameter, do:

```
    constructor(id: number, point: number, status = Status.NONE) {
        this.id = id;
        this.point = point;
        this.status = status;
    }
```

You can further reduce this to:

```
    constructor(public id: number, public point: number,
                public status = Status.NONE) {
    }
```

---

**Edit**: Also, because TypeScript is *structurally*, not *nominally* typed (see [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system)), you don't lose any type safety by returning a literal versus a class-constructed instance. Both versions of your code can safely be said to be returning a `Reward`. 
[TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmB3MAnAJtA3gKGtYA9gHYQAuKArsKQSgBQAOFARiAJbDRtoBc0ZKNkQDmASiwBfbFOyESpaAA8+CZOmgBeLNz4ByAIwAmACwBmAKy6JAbiA)

```
class Reward {
  constructor(public id: string) {}
}

// This is OK.
const x: Reward = {id: '12435'};
```

If `Reward` starts adding methods, then what you lose is the ability to create a `Reward` easily with your object literal.